# Rails routes to set of resources?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, routes

A typical Rails route like:

```
 resource :customer
```

Sets up routes for index, show, etc.

To access all the customers, I can use the route

```
/customers
```

To access a single customer, I use:

```
/customers/1
```

Whats the most concise, RESTful way to create a route and controller action that would allow a user to view a set of customers, i.e. something like

```
/customers/[1,2,3,4,5]
```

***Updated with rationale***

The use case:

- This action will be called via Javascript to provide details on selected users.  If a user selects 3 customers through the interface, I would like one request to pull info for all 3, instead of having to make 3 separate requests

Comment: How are these customers related?  For example, if I want to see customer 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5 all on the same page, why would I want to see those specific customers?

Comment: I'm thinking this could be cleaned up better with a little bit more information about your situation.

Comment: I'm still not convinced that "RESTful" means never using query parameters, which IMO may be a reasonable solution here.

Comment: @JacobWG I've thought down the same path...maybe adding a "group" model to represent a set of customers.  Since a user can select arbitrary customers, predefined groups won't work for my use case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just keep your routes simple: `resources :customers`.

The list of ids would be considered as the `:id` by the routes, and you would get `[1, 2, 3, 4]` in `params[:id]`.

Then in your controller, in a before_filter for example, you can check if the id matches a certain regexp (like... `/\[(\d,)*\d\]/`), and if it's the case you can extract the ids.

Comment: Wishing there was some idiomatic Rails/REST way to do this, but since there doesn't seem to be consensus on that your approach sounds like it would work.